# Interation and group

Tags: dart, iteration

I have a class `Account` that contains a list of `Feature` :

```dart
class Account{
...
<List>Feature features
```

and a feature is composed of :

```dart
class Feature {
    String name;
    String description;
    bool enabled;
    String category;
}
```

What I want to do is to display them and grouping them by their category. Algorithmically speaking, I don't know how to do. How to Iterate in order to group them. This is an exemple of what the result should be : 2 features that have "travel" as `category`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a map where the key are the category and value are a list of features:

```dart
class Feature {
  String name;
  String description;
  bool enabled;
  String category;

  Feature(this.name, this.category);

  String toString() => name;
}

class Account {
  List<Feature> features = [];
}

void main() {
  Account account = Account();
  account.features.add(Feature("a", "test 1"));
  account.features.add(Feature("b", "test 1"));
  account.features.add(Feature("c", "test 2"));

  final map = <String, List<Feature>>{};
  for (var feature in account.features) {
    map.update(feature.category, (list) => list..add(feature),
        ifAbsent: () => [feature]);
  }

  print(map);
}
```

Comment: Ok, I understand the logic behind this. When I tried it, there was an exception `ArgumentError (Invalid argument (key): Key not in map.: "travel")
`. What I understand from that, is that the keys have to be created first, before being updated, right ?

Comment: Okay, I just added `map.putIfAbsent(feature.category, () => []);` before the update, and it worked. Thank you for your help

Comment: Did you remember to add the "ifAbsent" part to the update method call where I create the list if the key are not in the map? It is a clever way to avoid putIfAbsent. :)

Comment: Oh no I did not. So that's why. Thanks !